# Cube and Square Root calculator

Tags: php

I'm learning php and I've got an exercise that I'm stuck at.
The exercise is to create a calculator in php that displays the cube and square root of the numbers from 1 to 10 and to display the results formatted as a table in HTML.

Is this correct?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Cube</th>    
<th>Square root</th>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td>
<?php
 //Cube 
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
echo "$i^3 = ". pow($i,3) . "<br />";
}
?>
</td>
<td>
<?php
 //Square Root
 for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
 echo "√$i = ".sqrt($i) . "<br />";
 }
 ?>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: If you try running it, and compare the answers it gives with the actual cubes and square roots, then you'll know if it is right or not

Comment: It is giving me the correct results but it's not separating each result by row.

Comment: That's because you're looping within a `<td>`, so everything is displayed inside that `<td>`... Loop around the `<tr>` and only display inside of the `<td>`

Comment: I've been trying to do it but it's giving me a syntax error. Where should I put the tags? Need help please

Comment: I was able to display the results separated but all of them were on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping only td, you need to loop tr and td both.
  please find below correct code.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>Cube and square</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <table border=1>
        <tr>
         <th>Cube</th>
         <th>Square root</th>
       </tr>
       <?php
       //Cube ans square
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $i . "^3 = " . pow($i, 3) . "</td>";
          echo "<td> √" . $i . " = " . sqrt($i) . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
       ?>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```